# Ansible seems server-centric. Can it be app-centric?

Tags: ansible

New to Ansible and looking for guidance and / or code in the following dilemma.

It seems like Ansible is server-centric, forcing you to think from point of view of a server which have roles applied, e.g. "this is a web and an email server, this one is database server, etc.". I'm not able to come up with a solution to say that app A should be deployed on Server X.

To me it feels more natural to think from the app perspective, e.g. "app A is mission-critical and needs to run on the ServerBig while the apps B and C can run on ServerSmall-N". I know you'll probably say that I should group servers into mission-critical and normal, but I don't want to run app B on every normal server, but just one, probably the one that is the least used at the moment. Also it doesn't feel natural.

Can Ansible be bent to be app-centric? If yes, does it even make sense? Should I convert and see the light?

Comment: This question strikes me as a sign that you are not sufficiently using virtualization in your environment.

Answer (score 5):

What you describe as your use-case ("app A needs to run on ServerBig") is exactly the same thing as saying "this is a web and e-mail server", except you're replacing "web" with "app A".  If you have separate "classes" for app A, app B, and app C, in the same way as you'd have for "web server", "email server", and "database server", you would allocate them in exactly the same way.

What you describe in the last part of your question, about running "app B" on just one lightly-loaded machine, is not a "configuration management" problem so much as it as a dynamic resource allocation problem, which is a *completely* different problem.  Some configuration management systems have components that do this, or at least attempt to do it, but in practice you're better off using something designed for the job.  Kubernetes appears to be the "current hawtness" in this area, as long as you're comfortable drinking the Docker Kool-aid and going all-container, all-the-time.  Otherwise, I don't have a specific recommendation, because a lot of it depends so much on your application deployment strategy.